# Get contacts in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to get the contact numbers in Android but as far as I found a tutorial, it puts out the number in ascending order, not in the order they appear in the contacts...

How can I modify the code to obtain the numbers in the exact order from my contact list??

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.NUMBER}, null,null, null);
ArrayList <String> nr_formatat = new ArrayList <String> ();
if (cursor != null) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext() == true)

        nr_formatat.add(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
    }
```

Comment: The default order for the contacts list is in ascending alphabetical order. Unless you freely rearrange your contacts list in some arbitrary order, in which case that order would be handled/stored by your native Contacts app. Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Supposing i have in contact list: (Anna, 0342) , (Lulu, 0311), (John, 0088); the order they appear is: 0088 , 0311 , 0342 so in Ascending Order, while I really want them by the names alphabetical order: 0342, 0311, 0088. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way. You need to query the number against the CONTACT_ID or else you won't have any correspondence between the two. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/).

Comment: thanks, in your tutorial: how do i get the phone number under this loop? while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
       // Do something with phones
          }

Comment: you don't have to change the way you get the phone number, you can still use getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER) method. the only change is to the query of the sqlite db.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your contacts are ordered in your contact list. Hit the menu button and tap on 'Display Options'. Other than that, you don't have enough information in your question to adequately answer it.

From what I can see, you're going about it the wrong way. I would look over this example application. It fetches the contacts differently than you and will allow you to sort it however you want.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BusinessCard/src/com/example/android/businesscard/index.html

Comment: It's in alphabetical order, but the numbers got are in ascending order :( as you know, we get contacts name and phone numbers from 2 separate places. I get the names in alphabetical order, while the numbers are ascending. I wish i could get a correspondence between them, i have to display the contact list

Answer (score 0):

Following should work if:
(Anna, 0342) has ID 1, (Lulu, 0311) has ID 2, (John, 0088) has ID 3

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.NUMBER}, null,null, new String[]{Phone.ID});
ArrayList <String> nr_formatat = new ArrayList <String> ();
if (cursor != null) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext() == true)

        nr_formatat.add(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
    }
```

The last variable of ContentResolver().query() takes the sortorder. So here you put something like the ID, if your contactlist also sorts on ID.
[ConecntResolver().Query() info here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)